# PyAutoGui on non-gnome OS (Lubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyautogui, xfce

Here's my - very simple - code :

```
import pyautogui

x, y = 1321, 367 #the coordinates i want to click on

while True:
    clickcolor = (75, 219, 106) #which is the tuple of my rgb value
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x,y,clickcolor) == True:
        pyautogui.leftClick(x,y)
```

So when I ran this code on **Lubuntu**, I got an error message that told me **to install 'gnome-screenshot'**. I installed it (with 'gnome-shell') on my system and when i ran the script again i got :

`** Message: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11.`

I tried to **uninstall the two gnome packages** and ran it again -> did'nt work
I tried to install **xfce screenshot** package -> did'nt work (maybe i did it wrong ?)
I tried the **getPixel() function** of pyautogui -> gave me the exact same error message

So now I am out of ideas to get my code work on my **non-gnome** system and i need your help

Thanks, M4elstr0m